# Model show from another html page

Tags: model, call

I have 2 html files name index.html, model.html. I have plenty of models and want to write all in model.html page and want to use it in index.html page.

I write my code as follows

But its not working, can some one suggest me my mistake? Please write full page html codes will help me a lot

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Load Modals from Another HTML File</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <!-- Button to open Modal 1 -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg"  onclick="loadModal('modal1')">Open Modal 1</button>

    <!-- Button to open Modal 2 -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" onclick="loadModal('modal2')">Open Modal 2</button>

    <!-- Button to open Modal 3 -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" onclick="loadModal('modal3')">Open Modal 3</button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <!-- Modal content will be loaded here -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- JavaScript code to load the modal content from another HTML file -->
    <script>
    function loadModal(modalId) {
        // Load the contents of the modal from the other HTML file
        $.get("model.html", function(data) {
            // Extract the modal content with the given ID from the loaded HTML
            var modalContent = $(data).find("#" + modalId).html();

            // Set the modal content in the current page's HTML
            $("#myModal .modal-content").html(modalContent);

            // Open the modal
            $("#myModal").modal("show");
        });
    }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

model.html as follows

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Model Page</title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="model1" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Model 1</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Some text in the first modal.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="model2" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Model 2</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Some text in the second modal.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="model3" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Model 3</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Some text in the third modal.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```